# Checking if IP Camera is connected or not with cv2 faster?

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, rtsp

I have code that works on 2 IP Cameras but before running my main algorithm I would like to check if my IP Cameras are connected or not. I wrote this code and i have used it before with 2 USB cameras now i am having a problem with IP Cameras.

```
import cv2 

def check_connnections():
    #Check cam1
    cam1_ok = False    
    cam1 = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://admin:Tom12345.@192.168.0.33:554/onvif1') 
    if cam1.isOpened():
        cam1_ok = True

    #Check cam2
    cam2_ok = False
    cam2 = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://admin:Tom12345.@192.168.0.33:554/onvif1') 
    if cam2.isOpened():
        cam2_ok = True

    print(f'Cam1 Connection Status: {cam1_ok}')
    print(f'Cam2 Connection Status: {cam2_ok}')


check_connnections()
```

Now if i plug the cameras i get:
`Cam1 Connection Status: True` , `Cam2 Connection Status: True` and when i unplug the cameras i expect `Cam1 Connection Status: False` , `Cam2 Connection Status: False` but  it takes 3 minutes for `cv2.VideoCapture()` function to finish and return `False`if the IP cameras are not connected  while it runs instantly for USB cameras. Is there a faster way to check this ?

I tried same thing with USB Cameras, i also tried `try:... except:pass` but i couldn't find i way.

Comment: You didn't say what cameras you are using!

Comment: You need to set/pass ffmpeg timeouts to cv2, and you should check If camera ok and exception Handling on your main algo not before, what is when cam goes offline before Main algo Runs or in it ;)

Comment: I am using HikVision 4MP POE Bullet cameras. I still have the same problem but i think i am going to ignore it.